# Reload bxSlider on window resize

Tags: javascript, reload, bxslider

I use bxSlider on my website. The slider should reload on window resize. With the code i actually use the slider is loadad on load and resize. But the slider is not reloaded but loaded the second time. So i have 2 loaded sliders. I need just to reload the slider and not load it again.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    /* BX SLIDER */
    $('#bannerslider').bxSlider({
        captions: true
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You have 2 bxSliders, yet I see code for one slider and it's not very helpful. Can you make a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @zer00ne, OP has one slider, the second one is unlikely created instead of reloading the first one, so posted code snippet is fine

Comment: There is just one bxSlider sorry my english is maybe not correct. So when i load the window, one bxSlider is loaded correct but on resize a second bxSlider is loaded. But i dont want to load another one but instead just reload the existing bxSlider.

Comment: @Peesen87 My bad, ok review my answer. This fix works so good I'll probably use it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Used 2 callbacks from the [bxSlider API](http://bxslider.com/options):

- `onSliderResize()` When the resize event is triggered, `reloadBX()` will call `.reloadSlider`, store the current index in `localStorage` and retrieve it to maintain index position instead of starting at the beginning after a reload.
- `onSliderLoad()` When load event is triggered, `checkBX()` will check the height of bxSlider, and if it is collapsed (0px), it will invoke `redrawSlider()`. That will force a reset graphically until it succeeds in forcing bxSlider to wake up.

This Snippet works fast, so I setup the console to show that it is working. Review it in full page mode of course. If for some reason the Snippet is broken (it does at times), you can test the demo at <kbd>[**Plunker**](http://embed.plnkr.co/oEpte6xZUABtjBeOFQnj/)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bxSlider Resize</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <style>
    img {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }
    /* Ruleset makes img centered. */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class='bx'>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/000/fff?text=1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/00f/fc0?text=2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/8de/fa6?text=3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/cb9/0ff?text=4">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/fff/000?text=5">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input id='cache' type='hidden'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <!-- The 3 console.logs facilitates debugging. 
//]  They are optional and are not essential for overall functioning.//-->
  <script>
    var bx = $('.bx').bxSlider({
      captions: true,
      // onResize 
      onSliderResize: reloadBX,
      // onLoad
      onSliderLoad: checkBX
    });

    /*
    Resize Callback 
    */ // Stores the current slide index.
    function reloadBX(idx) {
      localStorage.cache = idx;
      console.log('Reload on Slide: ' + idx);
      // Reloads slider, 
      ///goes back to the slide it was on before resize,
      ///removes the stored index.
      function inner(idx) {
        setTimeout(bx.reloadSlider, 0);
        var current = parseInt(idx, 10);
        console.log('RELOADED');
        bx.goToSlide(current);
        localStorage.removeItem("cache");
      }
    }

    /*
    Load Callback
    */ // If the slider height is collapsed, 
     /////invoke a repaint and stay on current index.
    function checkBX(idx) {
      var vp = $('.bx-viewport').height();
      console.log('View-port Height: ' + vp + 'px');
      while (vp <= 0) {
        bx.redrawSlider();
        console.log('REPAINT');
      }
 
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```